# SendInput() for keyboard - only uppercase

Tags: winapi, keyboard, sendinput

Quite funny. I just asked few minutes ago here [SendInput() for keyboard - only lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438110/sendinput-for-keyboard-only-lowercase/11438156#11438156), how to send letters upper case. The solution was to send shift before letter. But after turning shift on I can't turn it off...

I'm trying hard with KEYEVENTF_KEYUP flag like this:

```
INPUT Input = { 0 };
Input.type       = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.mi.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
Input.ki.wVk   = VK_LSHIFT;
SendInput( 1, &Input, sizeof( INPUT ) );

Input.type       = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.mi.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
Input.ki.wVk   = 'A';
SendInput( 1, &Input, sizeof( INPUT ) );

Input.type       = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.mi.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
Input.ki.wVk   = VK_LSHIFT;
SendInput( 1, &Input, sizeof( INPUT ) );

Input.type       = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Input.mi.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
Input.ki.wVk   = 'A';
SendInput( 1, &Input, sizeof( INPUT ) );
```

but it seems to not work at all. It always sends AA.

Thanks.

Comment: The left shift key is not a KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY.  Nor is A.

Comment: Furthermore, you're sending the "down" for `A` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with

```
Input.mi.dwFlags
```

it should be

```
Input.ki.dwFlags
```

thanks to rodrigo.

Another way is to use KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE flag. Then we have to scan our char using VkKeyScan() - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329(v=vs.85).aspx, which gives us virtual key code in low byte and state (shift, ctrl etc.) in high byte.

Due to using scan codes we have to map our virtual code to scan code by using MapVirtualKey() with MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC value, MSDN says:

> uCode is a virtual-key code and is translated into a scan code. If it
>   is a virtual-key code that does not distinguish between left- and
>   right-hand keys, the left-hand scan code is returned. If there is no
>   translation, the function returns 0.

and then pass it to the wScan field of the Input.ki structure, because according to MSDN if we use scan codes it ignores wVk and uses wScan, MSDN says:

> If specified, wScan identifies the key and wVk is ignored.

Therefore the code can look something like this:

```
INPUT Event = { 0 };

const SHORT key = VkKeyScan('a');
const UINT mappedKey = MapVirtualKey( LOBYTE( key ), 0 );

// Press shift key
Event.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
Event.ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey( VK_LSHIFT, 0 );
SendInput( 1, &Event, sizeof( Event ) );

// upper case 'A' (press down)
Event.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
Event.ki.wScan = mappedKey;
SendInput( 1, &Event, sizeof( Event ) );

//  release 'A'
Event.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
Event.ki.wScan = mappedKey;
SendInput( 1, &Event, sizeof( Event ) );

// Release shift key
Event.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
Event.ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey( VK_LSHIFT, 0 );
SendInput( 1, &Event, sizeof( Event ) );

const SHORT key1 = VkKeyScan('a');
const UINT mappedKey1 = MapVirtualKey( LOBYTE( key1 ), 0 );

// lower case 'a' (press down)
Event.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
Event.ki.wScan = mappedKey1;
SendInput( 1, &Event, sizeof( Event ) );

// release 'a'
Event.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
Event.ki.wScan = mappedKey1;
SendInput( 1, &Event, sizeof( Event ) );
```

If I have said something wrong, please correct me.

Comment: You've missed the whole point of SendInput, namely to put in arrays of input events that cannot be interrupted by real input events

Comment: You forgot to put unary OR KEYEVENTF_KEYUP in releasing the 'a'. @tobi, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this!  It was very helpful in debugging my code.  Here is my final version for those who need it.

```
void Type(const char* text) {
    INPUT ip[4] = {};

    for (; *text; text++) {
        int startInput = 1; // Assume 1 keyup and keydown pair.
        int nInputs = 2;

        if (HIBYTE(VkKeyScan(*text)) == 1) { // Set up SHIFT key and release
            startInput = 0;
            nInputs = 4;

            ip[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            ip[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
            ip[0].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(VK_LSHIFT, 0);

            ip[3] = ip[0];
            ip[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        }

        ip[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;  // Set up key and release
        ip[1].ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(LOBYTE(VkKeyScan(*text)), 0);
        ip[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;

        ip[2] = ip[1];
        ip[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

        SendInput(nInputs, &ip[startInput], sizeof(INPUT));
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```